# GET users endpoint returns 1003: Client id has no access to the account

Tags: autodesk-data-management, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to hit the GET users endpoint on the BIM 360 API using
[this guide](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/reference/http/users-GET/).

I have a Forge integration set on my BIM 360 Account Admin page, which includes Account Administration privileges. I followed the directions on the docs to remove the "b." from my hub id to get the account id, but when I hit the enpoint it returns "1003: Client has no access to the account"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This endpoint request a [2 legged access token](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/reference/http/authenticate-POST/) with `account:read` scope and a Forge App that was previously [provisioned within that BIM 360 Account](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/getting-started/manage-access-to-docs/).

Comment: I have both of these things.

Comment: Yes I am using US