# GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account_id/projects does not work

Tags: autodesk-bim360

Good day
I'm using GET https://developer.api.autodesk.com/hq/v1/accounts/:account/projects to return information on projects in my account. My app has been registered in https://admin.b360.autodesk.com/admin and I have a bearer token with account:read scope. When executing the call in Postman, I get the following response
{ "code": 1003, "message": "This client id has no access to the account." }
Regards,
Johan Kriek

Comment: Hi I was checking in your private inquiry on the same question, yet not got reply, while from the other duplicated post it looks you have accepted the answer from my colleague. Could you confirm if this question has been solved, or they are different question?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57878293/get-users-endpoint-returns-1003-client-id-has-no-access-to-the-account

Comment: Hi Xiaodong,
The question has not been resolved yet.

Comment: My apology, I thought you will contact us by emailing forge.help@autodesk.com, so did not respond your message here . If the problem still exists, could you send us the client id, snapshot on the id has been invited to the BIM account, snapshot of the Postman test? We will take a look. The ticket you posted by emailing is #4963